# How to make a view max. width with padding in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm figuring out how to make views adaptable to different screen sizes in SwiftUI. Currently, I'm trying to create a register screen that should have a certain maximum width, but still have a padding if the maximum width can't be applied on small screen sizes.

I'm using a GeometryReader at the root to retrieve the width of the view and to apply it to the "Register" button. So I tried adding a padding to the GeometryReader, but without success. The reason is, that you can set the maxWidth on the GeometryReader doesn't work, it gets wider than the screen size.

My code looks like this:

```
struct RegisterPage: View {
    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                TextField("login.email_placeholder", text: self.$email)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding(.bottom)
                TextField("login.username_placeholder", text: self.$username)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding(.bottom)
                TextField("login.password_placeholder", text: self.$password)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding(.bottom)
                Button(
                    action: {},
                    label: {
                        Text("login.register_button")
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: 500)
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got what you're trying to do, you can just use the `padding` modifier on the `GeometryReader`:

```
struct RegisterPage: View {
    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                TextField("login.email_placeholder", text: self.$email)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding(.bottom)
                TextField("login.username_placeholder", text: self.$username)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding(.bottom)
                TextField("login.password_placeholder", text: self.$password)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding(.bottom)
                Button(
                    action: {},
                    label: {
                        Text("login.register_button")
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: 500)
        .padding(50)
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** look the result with `maxWidth = 10000`

[image]

Comment: I tried this. But the real issue is, that if you set a maxWidth that is wider than the actual screen, the real width doesn't get set to the screen width. It still uses the maxWidth which leads to the overflow shown above.

Comment: @G.Marc are you sure? Look at my edit in the answer. I set maxWidth to 10000 and everything is sized correctly (be sure to have the latest xCode Beta, that is now xCode Beta 5).

Comment: This is exactly what I want! I will test again later. Are on on beta 5 as well?

Comment: @G.Marc Yes, I'm on xCode 11 beta 5 and MacOS Catalina beta 5.

Comment: Thanks @superpuccio, it really works. Don't really know what I was doing wrong before... :-)